# A function/distribution which satisfies an integral equation. (sounds bizzare)

Tags: real-analysis, integral-equations

I think I need a function, $f(x)$ such that $\large{\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x)\,d{x} = \frac{1}{(x_2-x_1)}}$ $\forall x_2>x_1>0$. Wonder such a function been used or studied by someone, or is it just more than insane to ask for such a function? I guess it has to be some distribution, and if so, I'd like to know more about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for your function you can easely find $x_1 <x_2 < x_3$ so that

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x) \, dx + \int_{x_2}^{x_3} f(x) \, dx \neq \int_{x_1}^{x_3} f(x) \, dx$$

so no such function can exists.

Actually you can prove this way that there exists no measure $m$ so that

$$ m([x_1,x_2])=\frac{1}{x_2-x_1} \,.$$

so in particular there is no absolutely continuous measure to satisfy that relation.

Comment: You don't have to look far, because *any* such $x_1<x_2<x_3$ will work.

Answer (score 4):

No such $f(x)$ can exist.  Such a function $f(x)$ would have antiderivative $F(x)$ that satisfies $$F(x_2)-F(x_1)=\frac{1}{x_2-x_1}$$ for all $x_2>x_1>0$.

Take the limit as $x_2\rightarrow \infty$ of both sides; the right side is 0 (hence the limit exists), while the left side is  $$\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} F(x)\right)-F(x_1)$$

Hence $F(x_1)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} F(x)$ for all $x_1$.  Hence $F(x)$ is constant, but no constant function satisfies the relationship desired.

Comment: What if $f(x)$ is only Lesbegue integrable? Then it doesn't have an antiderivative, but I suspect your answer can be modified a little to show that it doesn't work in that case either...

Comment: @N.S., is it true that if $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ exists for all $b$, and is uniformly bounded, then $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ exists as well?  If so, that integral must be zero for all $a$, then subtracting two such will break the relation.

Comment: Probably not. I think that $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: But, if you replace the word antiderivative by $F(x) =\int_a^x f(x) dx$ you can prove that $F(x)$ is constant on $[a,\infty)$....